# Output wstringstream by blocks issue

Tags: c++, stringstream, wstring

I have some issue with reading wstringstream data. Code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::wstringstream buf(L"dsadsadsad dsadsadsad sadsadsadsad sa dsadsadsads dasdsadsa");
    wchar_t sendbuf[5];
    wmemset(sendbuf, 0, 5);

    while (buf.read(sendbuf, 5))
    {
        std::wcout << sendbuf;
        wmemset(sendbuf, 0, 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it do not print out the whole data, Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::wostream::operator<<` takes a `wchar_t*` parameter, so it can't know the length of your buffer. You need an extra space in your buffer for the terminating zero.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::wstringstream buf(L"dsadsadsad dsadsadsad sadsadsadsad sa dsadsadsads dasdsadsa");
    wchar_t sendbuf[6];
    wmemset(sendbuf, 0, 6);

    while (buf.read(sendbuf, 5))
    {
        std::wcout << sendbuf;
        wmemset(sendbuf, 0, 6);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can alternatively use `std::wcout.write()` instead of `std::wcout <<`, then you don't need to null-terminate `sendbuf` at all, eg: `std::wcout.write(sendbuf, 5);` Also, `buf.read()` will set `buf.gcount()` to the number of characters actual read, if you want to use that value instead of hard-coding the `5`.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading one `wchar_t` more than should be into `buf`, thus destroying the zero termination you did with `wmemset(sendbuf, 0, 5);` there.
If you change the read amount in the loop

```
    while (buf.read(sendbuf, 4))
                          // ^ change
```

it works as intended.

See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/532d220444a7f587).